# Iterating over groups in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the following data:

```
cte1
===========================
m_ids    |p_id       |level
---------|-----------|-----
{123}    |98         |1
{123}    |111        |2
{432,222}|215        |1
{432,222}|215        |1
{432,222}|240        |2
{432,222}|240        |2
{432,222}|437        |3
{432,222}|275        |3
```

I have to perform the following operation:

1. Extract `p_id` by the following algorithm

   1. For every row with same `m_ids`
   2. In each group:
      2.I. Group records by `p_id`
      2.II. Order desc records by `level`
      2.III. Select `p_id` with exact count as the `m_ids` length and with the biggest `level`

So far I fail to write this algorithm completely, but I wrote (probably wrong where I'm getting `array_length`) this for the last part of it:

```
SELECT id 
FROM   grouped_cte1 
GROUP  BY id, 
          level 
HAVING Count(*) = array_length(grouped_cte1.m_ids, 1) 
ORDER  BY level DESC 
LIMIT  1
```

where `grouped_cte1` for `m_ids={123}` is

```
m_ids    |p_id       |level
---------|-----------|-----
{123}    |98         |1
{123}    |111        |2
```

and for `m_ids={432,222}` is

```
m_ids    |p_id       |level
---------|-----------|-----
{432,222}|215        |1
{432,222}|215        |1
{432,222}|240        |2
{432,222}|240        |2
{432,222}|437        |3
{432,222}|275        |3
```

etc.

2) Combine query from p.1 with the following. The following extracts `p_id` with `level=1` for each `m_ids`:

```
select m_ids, p_id from cte1 where level=1 --also selecting m_ids for joining later`
```

which results in the following:

```
m_ids    |p_id
---------|----
{123}    |98  
{432,222}|215
```

Desirable result:

```
m_ids    |result_1   |result_2
---------|-----------|--------
{123}    |111        |98
{432,222}|240        |215
```

So could anyone please help me solve **the first part** of algorithm and *(optionally)* combine it in a single query with the second part?

**EDIT:** So far I fail at:
1. Breaking the presented table into subtables by `m_ids` while iterating over it.
2. Performing computation of `array_length(grouped_cte1.m_ids, 1)` for corresponding rows in query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of the query you're on the right track, but you need to change the grouping logic and then join again to the table to filter it out by highest level per m_ids for which you could use `DISTINCT ON` clause combined with proper sorting:

```
select 
  distinct on (t.m_ids)
  t.m_ids, t.p_id, t.level
from cte1 t
join (
  select
    m_ids,
    p_id
  from cte1
  group by m_ids, p_id
  having count(*) = array_length(m_ids, 1)
  ) as g using (m_ids, p_id)
order by t.m_ids, t.level DESC;
```

This would give you:

```
   m_ids   | p_id | level
-----------+------+-------
 {123}     |  111 |     2
 {432,222} |  240 |     2
```

And then when combined with second query (using `FULL JOIN` for displaying purposes, when the first query is missing such conditions) which I modified by adding distinct since there can be (and in fact is) more than one record for `m_ids, p_id` pair with first level it would look like:

```
select 
  coalesce(r1.m_ids, r2.m_ids) as m_ids,
  r1.p_id AS result_1,
  r2.p_id AS result_2
from (
  select 
    distinct on (t.m_ids)
    t.m_ids, t.p_id, t.level
  from cte1 t
  join (
    select
      m_ids,
      p_id
    from cte1
    group by m_ids, p_id
    having count(*) = array_length(m_ids, 1)
    ) as g using (m_ids, p_id)
  order by t.m_ids, t.level DESC
  ) r1
full join (
  select distinct m_ids, p_id
  from cte1
  where level = 1
  ) r2 on r1.m_ids = r2.m_ids
```

giving you result:

```
   m_ids   | result_1 | result_2
-----------+----------+----------
 {123}     |      111 |       98
 {432,222} |      240 |      215
```

that looks different from what you've expected but from my understanding of the logic it is the correct one. If I misunderstood anything, please let me know.

---

Just for the sake of logic explanation, one point:

Why m_ids with {123} returns 111 for result_1?

- for group of `m_ids = {123}` we have two distinct `p_id` values
- both `98` and `111` account for the condition of equality count with the `m_ids` length
- `p_id = 111` has a higher level, thus is chosen for the result_1

Comment: You exactly right, I really made a mistake in "desirable result"! Your answer is incredibly helpful!

Comment: The same for `m_ids = {432,222}` I suppose. Glad I could help.

Comment: Actually, something went wrong with the second query. When I tried it on the real data, I noticed empty values in result_1 column (in fact, most of them are empty), but the first query works like a clock.

Comment: I have described this may be the case since we're using FULL JOIN but I doubt there is anything wrong with it, since your second question is saying about combining queries 1 and 2 but not saying how. This is the case when there are m_ids which length of array doesn't equal number of p_id's for this value but it has records with level 1.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not completely sure why (yet), but on the real data when I try even the first query, as it turned out, the amount of resulting rows is 24, while the amount of unique combinations of m_ids (which is the target) is 76. So something is wrong even with the first query, though for the cases where it did produce output, it is correct.

Comment: This is because it discards rows not meeting this condition:`having count(*) = array_length(m_ids, 1)`.

Comment: Yep, thanks again, there was a mistake in cte which I used to pass my data to your query :D